# What is this codomain?

Tags: notation

I was presented with a function $f:X$-->$2^X$ and I'm not sure what is meant by the codomain $2^X$. Any ideas?

Comment: this is the defenition of codomain of a fucntion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is the power set of $X$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure what is meant by "$2$ being defined as $\{0,1\}$, but in this case, would $f$ then be a function that takes an element of $X$ and returns a function $g:X$-->$\{a,b\}$ for $a,b$ in $R$?

Comment: The reason why "2" can be viewed as $\{0,1\}$ is due to the way natural numbers are constructed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers To answer your question, we can view $2^S$ as the set of all functions $f:S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$. (This notation is confusing but just accept it for now). Now consider a subset $X \subset S$. We identify each $s\in S$ as 0 if $s\in X$ and 1 if $s\notin X$. This way you see that $X$ induces a map $f:S\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ mapping each $s\in S$ just the way we defined above.